# "[ ]" operator accessing "[0]" value

Tags: pine-script

What is the meaning of the " Tsl[0] " used in line9,11,12,13 on this page?

https://www.tradingview.com/script/2raJpSpw-Supertrend-Filter/

I checked the value of " Tsl[0] " and found that the variable was the same as " Tsl[1] ".

Is this related to PineScript version differences?

```
///@version=2
study("Supertrend Filter555",overlay=true)
//
Pd=input(200)
Factor=input(0.9)
//
P = pow(Pd,2)
a = 2/(P+1)
d = abs(close - nz(Tsl[0],hl2))

////////////////////////////////////
e = nz(Tsl[0],hl2)
f = Tsl[0]
g = hl2
h = Tsl[1]

plot(e,transp=0)
plot(f,transp=0)
plot(g,transp=0)
plot(h,transp=0)
////////////////////////////////////


t = a*d+(1-a)*nz(t[1],d)
src = Factor*nz(Tsl[1],hl2) + (1-Factor)*close
Up=nz(Tsl[1],hl2)-t
Dn=nz(Tsl[1],hl2)+t
//
TrendUp=src[1]>TrendUp[1]? max(Up,TrendUp[1]) : Up
TrendDown=src[1]<TrendDown[1]? min(Dn,TrendDown[1]) : Dn
//
Trend = src > TrendDown[1] ? 1: src< TrendUp[1]? -1: nz(Trend[1],1)
Tsl = Trend==1? TrendDown : TrendUp
css = Tsl > Tsl[1] ? #f1a1e7 : Tsl < Tsl[1] ? #eeaddf : na
plot(Tsl,color=fixnan(css),transp=0)
```

Comment: I found out that Pine Script V2  had forward referencing.  But I still don't know why the author used "Tsl[0]" instead of "Tsl[1]".   This is the article I referred to. [Pine version 3 migration guide : Forward-referenced variables are removed][link](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/appendix/Pine_version_3_migration_guide.html#forward-referenced-variables-are-removed)

Answer (score 0):

`[]` in pinescript is called [History reference operator](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Operators.html#history-reference-operator).

`Tsl[0]` and `Tsl` are the same thing. `Tsl[1]` would be `Tsl`'s previous value.

In this code, `Tsl`'s value remains the same over many bars so that's why you think `Tsl[0]` and `Tsl[1]` are the same but they are not. Go to the place where `Tsl`'s value changes and you will see.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I had the same idea as you.But the strange thing is that the values of Tsl[0] and Tsl[1] are changing at the same time.

Am I doing something wrong?

Also, another question arises.
Why am I getting a Tsl[0] value that have not calculated?